# How to fill AJAX with values from multiple inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So i have an AJAX function and I want to search every element with particular class, take its value and add it into the AJAX in the right format. Is that possible?

I have this AJAX function:

```
function sendOrders(button) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "external_file.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            /*Here I need to add the data*/
            GameID: "'.$_SESSION['GameID'].'",
            Round: "'.$round.'",
            UserID: "'.$_SESSION['UserID'].'",
        }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        $("#DEBUG").html(msg);
    }); 
};
```

and I need to collect data from hidden-type inputs on the page with class="order".

I know that I can acces each element by class with jquery, but I have no idea how to add the properties to my AJAX, when it's already written. Number of those elements is variable and they have non-repeating ids, class is the same. Inputs look like this:

```
<input class="order" type="hidden" name="some_name" id="some_id" value="some_value">
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: So you don't know how many input values you'll be adding to your AJAX?

Comment: You could, and this is a little crazy, add these hidden elements to a `form` and set their `name` attributes to be the same as the key you want in your data. Then, when you post, just use `$(form).serializeArray()` for `data` (since it appears as though you're not using JSON). This is pretty much what HTML forms were created for.

Comment: I agree just put them in a `form` and then serialize them `data: $("#my-form").serialize()`. Easiest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to make that ajax call with several different values that you get from the inputs with class order?

Assuming you want to just add the value from those fields, you can do something pretty simple:

First, update your ajax function with an additional input variable,

```
function sendOrders(button, val) {
$.ajax({
    url: "external_file.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        value : val,
        GameID: "'.$_SESSION['GameID'].'",
        Round: "'.$round.'",
        UserID: "'.$_SESSION['UserID'].'",
    }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    $("#DEBUG").html(msg);
}); 
};
```

Then, to get data from all of your 'order' class inputs, you can use Jquery's 'each' function. For example, if you want the value from each of those inputs, you can use your new sendOrder function in the each function:

```
$('.order').each(function(){
    sendOrder(buttonId, $(this).val())
});
```

Not quite sure how you are using 'button' in your ajax function, but I assume it's associated with your save or submit button, so buttonId would be whatever the id is of that button. This will iterate over all inputs with class order and make the ajax call with those values.

If you're using the button as a submit you can probably take it out all together from the ajax function, and have something like this:

```
function sendOrders(val) {
$.ajax({
    url: "external_file.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        value : val,
        GameID: "'.$_SESSION['GameID'].'",
        Round: "'.$round.'",
        UserID: "'.$_SESSION['UserID'].'",
    }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    $("#DEBUG").html(msg);
}); 
};
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
    $('.order').each(function(){
        sendOrder(buttonId, $(this).val())
    });
 });
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to send each input value separately with different AJAX call. If that is true, I would have to edit the external_file.php to work with it.
I think I will use the tips from comments above but anyway thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Create the data object, loop over all the inputs, and add the values to the object.

```
function sendOrders(button) {
    var data = {
        GameID: "'.$_SESSION['GameID'].'",
        Round: "'.$round.'",
        UserID: "'.$_SESSION['UserID'].'",
    };
    $(button).closest("form").find("input[type=hidden]").each(function() {
        data[this.name] = this.value;
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "external_file.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: data
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        $("#DEBUG").html(msg);
    }); 
};
```